# How to run node.js application on pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am new to pm2 manager and ssh. I developed one project in node.js and hosted into pm2 and ssh.That's Working fine and give correct output
Now my question is
Same way i hosted another project into pm2 server and then i follow below procedure to run this application.
Step1: ssh and Mycredentials
step2: cd folder projectname
step3 : pm2 start www
That shows Done.
I will run url i didn't get output default it shows first project ouput\
please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Start your pm2 service with name argument to differentiate with multiple services

```
pm2 start www --name="my-sample-app1"
pm2 start index.js --name="my-sample-app2"
```

In order to list out the running process, enter the following command,

```
pm2 list
```

Using this you can debug the list of running process

To know the detailed information about your running process, use the following command

```
pm2 show my-sample-app1
pm2 show my-sample-app2
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried but not working.
**pm2 stop appname**
**pm2 delete appname**
After enter above commands it show process is deleted,Then i enter second project and
 **pm2 start www**
but i got first project output